# swipe slidebox vertically

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

I would like to create a slide box with Ionic which you can slide and swipe through vertically. I want to know if there is a way to achieve this using CSS.

I have attempted to use the Jssor slider which has a vertical slider.

```html
<ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide><img src="../img/awardvote-img.png"></ion-slide>
    <ion-slide><img src="../img/awardvote-img1.png"></ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

This is all the code I have so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ghadeer/wzx768zp/12/ check this

Comment: hmm, where exactly would I put the javascript? on page in script tags?